# number repeated twice in the variable

Tags: c++, c

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
  int a = 101;
  return 0;
}
```

Question : How do I know that the number (1) is repeated twice in the variable

Comment: You use your eyeballs and determine it. If you want a more programmatic answer, you need to post a question that's more specific than this... such as posting what you've tried and how it was different from your expectations.

Comment: This may help you decide: [Is Anything Real?](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=L45Q1_psDqk)

Comment: @mah your eyeballs :D

Comment: Take a look at [What is the fastest way to check for duplicate digits of a number?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4801487/what-is-the-fastest-way-to-check-for-duplicate-digits-of-a-number)

Comment: #include <iostream>
     #include <algorithm>

     using namespace std;

     int main()
     {
         int a = 101;
         std::string s = std::to_string(a);
         size_t n = std::count(s.begin(), s.end(), '1');
         //now you have number of "1" in n. Do whatever you want this.
         return 0;
     }

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you look at the code, you will see that the number `101` is assigned to the variable `a` and that number has the digit `1` twice in its decimal representation. So direct inspection is the way to go. I wouldn't even write the code for such a trivial requirement.

Comment: +1 This is **the** right answer.

Comment: +1 This kind of reasoning should be taught at Computer Science 101.

Answer (score 3):

Use modulus 10 and division 10 to find it. Rough idea is,

```
while( a > 0 )
{
    if( a % 10 == 1 )count_one++;
    a=a/10;
}
```

Comment: thanks for all members